# How to move methods to a second file to call from first - Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, move

I need some help with moving methods so that I can have less code on the "client" (First file). I want to be able to call the methods so that the program works as it does now. I have tried do it myself, but I can not get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

The methods I wish to move are the paintComponent, PanelListener, and PanelMotionListener

Here is the first file.

```
/******************/
/* IMPORT SECTION */
/******************/
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**************/
/* MAIN CLASS */
/**************/
public class Prog2 extends JPanel
{
    private Prog2_Server c1, c2;
    private Prog2_Server selectedRect;
    private int x,y;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();
        theGUI.setTitle("GUI Example");
        theGUI.setSize(500,500);
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Prog2 panel = new Prog2(Color.white);
        Container pane = theGUI.getContentPane();
        pane.add(panel);
        theGUI.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Prog2(Color backColor)
    {
        setBackground(backColor);
        c1 = new Prog2_Server(300,50,100,200, Color.red);
        c2 = new Prog2_Server(50,50,100,200, Color.blue);
        selectedRect = null;
        addMouseListener(new PanelListener());
        addMouseMotionListener(new PanelMotionListener());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        c1.fill(g);
        c2.draw(g);
    }

    private class PanelListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            // Select a circle if it contains the mouse coords
            x= e.getX();
            y= e.getY();

            if(c1.containsPoint(x,y))
            {
                selectedRect = c1;
            }
            else if (c2.containsPoint(x,y))
            {
                selectedRect = c2;
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            // deselect the selected rectangle
            x= e.getX();
            y= e.getY();
            selectedRect = null;
        }
    }

    private class PanelMotionListener extends MouseMotionAdapter
    {
        public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e)
        {
            // compute the distance and move the selected circle
            int newX = e.getX();
            int newY = e.getY();
            int dx = newX - x;
            int dy = newY -y;

            if(selectedRect != null)
            {
                selectedRect.move(dx,dy);
            }

            x=newX;
            y=newY;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the second file.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Prog2_Server extends JPanel
{
    private int width, length, xCoord, yCoord;
    private Color color;
    private Prog2_Server c1, c2;
    private Prog2_Server selectedRect;
    private int x,y;


    public Prog2_Server(int xC, int yC, int x, int y, Color c)
    {
        width = x;
        length = y;
        xCoord = xC;
        yCoord = yC;
        color = c;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        Color oldColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawRect(xCoord,yCoord,width,length);
        g.setColor(oldColor);
    }

    public void fill(Graphics g)
    {
        Color oldColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawRect(xCoord,yCoord,width,length);
        g.setColor(oldColor);
    }

    public boolean containsPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        return ((xCoord <= x && x <= (xCoord + width)) && (yCoord <= y && y <= (yCoord + length)));
    }

    public void move(int xAmount, int yAmount)
    {
        xCoord = xCoord + xAmount;
        yCoord = yCoord + yAmount;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't split a class across files.  If the methods make logical sense to be in that class, then leave them there, or make a new utility/helper class.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your first class to replace the private classes with a public class (in a different file, one for each class).  The create the appropriate objects in your "first" file to use the classes you have.

Answer (score 0):

Note that PanelListener and PanelMotionListener aren't methods, they are classes. You can move each of them to a different file, but they wouldn't be private classes any more and you would need to do some changes in your code. I would not advise that.

If having too much codes bugs you, Eclipse probably lets you hide it (with a minus sign on the left of each method or class).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of moving part of the PanelListener class to the second file

add a method in the server

```
public static Prog2_Server clientMousePressed (MouseEvent e, Prog2_Server c1, Prog2_Server c2)
{
    int x, y;
    // Select a circle if it contains the mouse coords
    x= e.getX();
    y= e.getY();

    if(c1.containsPoint(x,y))
    {
        return c1;
    }
    else if (c2.containsPoint(x,y))
    {
        return c2;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in the client file you can call the static method declared in server like the folowing:

```
private class PanelListener extends MouseAdapter
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {  
        selectedRect = Prog2_Server.clientMousePressed(e, c1, c2);
    }
//...   
}
```